# Flutter Wrong full snapshot version

Tags: flutter, dart

I was using Flutter and it was okay, until I run the -flutter upgrade. After that, when I put in debug mode, even when the emulator is already on, debug console shows this message: 
Wrong full snapshot version, expected '0c73eb70aa4d30f450273cb424be8c62' found '1d7acad1540192ac459cf60344efb7c1'

Isolate creation failed

Compiler failed on C:\Users\myname\Documents\projetos\16Apps\projeto4\lib\main.dart
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
Exited (sigterm)

When I try -flutter doctor, it says that no issues was found.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar issue reported here at

```
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16103
```

try to use

```
git clean -xffd
```